# Oracle: Delete selected rows from multiple tables at one shot

Tags: oracle

There is a common column pl_id in 6 Oracle tables. But there is no foreign key concept implemented. The requirement is-- if multiple rows corresponding to 'n' pl_id(s) are getting deleted from one table, records pertaining to same 'n' pl_id(s) in other 5 tables must also delete automatically.
Checked below URLs:
[Optimal way to DELETE specified rows from Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092407/optimal-way-to-delete-specified-rows-from-oracle)
[Delete all rows in a table based on another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590799/delete-all-rows-in-a-table-based-on-another-table)

Checked many other sites as well, but couldn't find help that I am seeking for, possibly I am using wrong key word while searching.

Comment: Sorry for the miss, the column pl_id contains unique values. Also, the 'n' values should not be entered manually to delete records from rest tables. It should automatically detect the deletion from one table and delete corresponding records form rest tables.

Comment: Why not introduce foreign key concept in other tables?

Comment: Yes I understand foreign key can resolve the issue at ease by CASCADE DELETE, but is out of scope.

Comment: See if [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5033906925164) helps.

Comment: I am afraid I could not find any solution in the above link.

Comment: What about triggers?

Comment: @Nitish, since I am new to triggers, can you please provide a sample trigger based upon the scenario that's provided?

Comment: @Anshu: This [simple tutorial](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_delete.php) should help you.

Comment: @Nitish, I checked the AFTER DELETE and BEFORE DELETE triggers and understood the purpose. But here, I am sorry if I couldn't make it clear, the sole purpose is to delete the records from rest tables having 'n' pl_id(s) which would be deleted from table 1 first. Can you please help in linking FOR EACH ROW and BEGIN block in trigger with my objective?

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW` is used to determine whether a trigger must fire when each row is deleted. After `BEGIN`, you can write `DELETE` statements for the remaining 5 tables using `:old.pl_id`.

Comment: @Nitish, Thank you. Can you please see if this is correct: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DUMMY_TEST_TRIGGER1
AFTER DELETE
ON TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE JOB_STAGE_ID := :OLD.JOB_STAGE_ID
END;
/

Comment: While deleting record from table 1, this error is displayed-- Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'I60_SCH04.DUMMY_TEST_TRIGGER1' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Hi all, solution found: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
AFTER DELETE
ON TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE PL_ID = :OLD.PL_ID;
DELETE FROM TABLE3 WHERE PL_ID = :OLD.PL_ID; DELETE FROM TABLE4 WHERE PL_ID = :OLD.PL_ID;DELETE FROM TABLE5 WHERE PL_ID = :OLD.PL_ID; END;
/

Comment: @Anshu: You are welcome. Hope you have found the solution